# plpgsql: how to write transaction which creates trigger and function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I need to make trigger and function if I have special IP address.
If I create trigger and function alone, thats fine. But something wrong
in my syntax. I've got syntax error at or near "declare"
My version of Postgres is 11.

```
do 
$$
declare
    server_ip_adr text := host(inet_server_addr());
    checking_statement bool := server_ip_adr in ('10.11.11.11', '10.22.22.22');
BEGIN
    IF checking_statement then 
                        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_ddl_trigger()
                              RETURNS event_trigger
                             LANGUAGE plpgsql
                              AS $$
                              declare massage_error _text;
```

Help me executing this statement.
Its long, bot postgres gives error on last statement - declare massage_error _text;
The error is ERROR:
syntax error at or near "declare"

p.s. I cant place the whole code here - Ive got error.
Can you suggest where in internet I can save code and give link here

Comment: Maybe you could share your code? Otherwise it's gonna be a wild guess...

Comment: Wait guys. I cant for reasons i dont know. Error ocurs

Comment: Can you help? Where can i store code and give link here?

Comment: How could someone help you with this? It's not even half the code that you need to get something valid, let alone something functionally correct. It looks like you need dynamic SQL in your function. But to be honest, are you 100% sure want something like this? There is so much that could go wrong, I would not recommend this to somebody without a good number of years experience with plpgsql. Dynamic sql in a function: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for help. Found a solution. I had to add explicit statements in $$. Because query didn't find out where one block starts
and where the letter. Thats why start and finish of statement 'DO' I marked as $$, and inner function creation like  $function$
So write code looks like:

```
do 
$$
declare
    server_ip_adr text := host(inet_server_addr());
    checking_statement bool := server_ip_adr in ('10.56.71.11', '10.56.71.11');
BEGIN
    
    IF checking_statement then 
                        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_ddl_trigger()
                              RETURNS event_trigger
                             LANGUAGE plpgsql
                              AS $function$
                              declare message_error _text;
```